# Does the Java compiler remove unreachable if statements that check for enum constants?

Tags: java, enums

Suppose I have the following enum:

```
public enum BooleanEnum {
   FALSE(false), TRUE(true);
   private BooleanEnum(boolean value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
   private final boolean value;
   public boolean value() {
       return value;
   }
}
```

Would Java remove the following code from the compiled code?

```
if (BooleanEnum.FALSE.value()) {
     //would the contents here get removed?
}
```

I know this would be the case if I were using static final constants, for example in:

```
static final boolean DEBUG = false;
if (DEBUG) { x=3; }
```

The Java compiler would remove the `if (DEBUG) { x=3; }` code.

If the enum code above does not get removed, would there be any way to make it so without going back to static constants?

Comment: what did you asked is totally choas.. ? please review your question and try to be more specific.

Comment: Q:  Does the Java compiler removes unreachable ... [code]?  A: Yes.  If code is truly unreachable, it will generally be detected by the compiler and removed from the .class file: https://briangordon.github.io/2014/01/javac-optimizations.html.  SUGGESTION: get a copy of [jd decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) and experiment yourself!

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks but the link you shared does not mention enums.

Comment: There's no absolute, "one size fits all" answer. Get the JD Decompiler and experiment with your particular Java compiler(s) and your particular code example(s).  Post back what you find :)

Comment: Did you mean to write `if (BooleanEnum.FALSE.value())` instead of `if (Boolean.FALSE.value())`?

Comment: Yes, just fixed it. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler throw errors on truly unreachable code?

Comment: Some IDEs show warnings for stuff like `if(false)` but it should compile.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `javac` to do that. The JIT might just though.

Comment: Why would you care if the code is included or not? I guess that at runtime (after the JIT compiler did its job) it should not matter if the code is there or not from a performance point of view. The only other possible issue I see is the size of the compiled code. Do you have a problem with the size or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you read already [JLS #14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).

> Would Java remove the following code from the compiled code?
>   if (BooleanEnum.FALSE.value()) {
>       //would the contents here get removed?
>   }

No. Because `value()` is not a compile time constant value. It could return `true` or `false`. See following snippet.

```
static enum BooleanEnum {
    FALSE(false), TRUE(true);

    private BooleanEnum(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    private final boolean value;

    public boolean value() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler does no logical analysis during the compilation. Wheras `static final boolean DEBUG = false` is clearly constant during the compile time and could be used for `conditional compilation` purpose.

> If the enum code above does not get removed, would there be any way to make it so without going back to static constants?

Using static constants is the only way.

Depending what you want to achieve there could be other solutions. e.g. using a simple class file which is generated before the compilation based on your conditions.

```
public class CompileFlag {
    static final boolean DEBUG = false;
}
```

Comment: @BileshGanguly He's just answered that.